# Get the request body in custom filter java Play framework

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I've read https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaHttpFilters#more-powerful-filters, but I still don't understand how to access the request body inside the filter chain. I'm trying to make an accumulator but I'm not sure how to access the nextFilter in the apply method of EssentialAction. If anyone knows how to actually access the request body inside the filter chain let me know! I'm working in java

Comment: What are you exactly trying to achieve? Maybe filters are not the best choice for you.

Comment: If the request was sent to the wrong server by the client then I want to be able to proxy it to the correct one. The issue is I need the request body to do some, but I can't seem to access it in the filter chain

Answer (score -1):

In order to parse the body of the request, you can use Action composition in your filters. You must actually stream / parse the body in the filter manually, and then let the framework parse it again as it passes to your controller.

Here is a good article on how this can be achieved.

https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/02/understanding-the-play-filter-api.html